# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported on submit

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to get the request parameter values this page is added in my

spring security:

```
    <security:http pattern="/users/reset*" security="none" />
```

form:

```
 <div class="input_form" style="margin:0 auto;width:500px;padding:14px;">
        <sf:form action="${contextPath}users/resetpassword" method="POST">
            <label>User Name</label> <input type="text" name="username">
            <label>Email Address</label> <input type="text" name="email">
            <button type="submit">Reset Password</button> <br/>
        </sf:form>
    </div>

@RequestMapping(value = "resetPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView resetPassword(@RequestParam("email") String email,
        @RequestParam("username") String username) {
    logger.info("Enter email reset password");
    logger.info("user name:" + username);
    logger.info("email address:" + email);
    return null;
}
```

Now when I am trying to submit the form I am getting this warning 405 Request method 'Post' not supported on submit
Error:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Comment: You need to ask a question, not just post code.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question to indicate what URL your form is trying to post, and what parameters are being supplied?

Comment: / should be present after ${contextPath}/users/resetpassword

Comment: I have already defined <c:url var="contextPath" value="/"/>
while adding ${contextPath}/users/resetpassword the URL is look like "/scgid//users/resetpassword"

Comment: Gosh! case sensitive typo error in URL Mapping